# How to transfer disabled app

Tags: facebook-apps

lately my facebook account got disabled as a 'bad app developer' without any warning. The thing is all of the apps, where I was listed as an admin got disabled, even though they didn't have any negative feedback. Some applications, where my collegues were listed as admins can be restored from their accounts (and they got enabled as they are working correctly). But there is one, where only I was listed as admin, and I can't find a way to send an appeal. There is a notice about a transfer process in the mail I received saying

> For more information on recovering or transferring these applications, please visit our FAQ page: http://www.facebook.com/help?faq=17556

But the FAQ page says it can't be found.

Please can somebody point to a tutorial or step-by-step guide how to transfer the app to another account, so I can get enabled again.

Thanks many times.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no way to recover/transfer the app to another account. All you can really do is set up a new app and point it to the same web address. That being said your account was disabled for a reason, so I would read up on the terms and conditions to find out exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: Because a lot of companies (like facebook) don't get around to updating the emails they send and sometimes end up with broke links in them :(